# want to update my `ng-model' value angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
<div style="width:100%">
       <input name="myInput1"  id="txt_name" class="search-pannel" ng-model="query.name" type="text" placeholder="Type something" ng-change="search(query.name)">{{query.name}}
       <input type="text" id="txt_name2" />
</div>
```

I want to update my `ng-model="query.name"`

```
 if ($rootScope.searchText != undefined) {

    //$scope.query = $rootScope.searchText;
    //$scope.query.name = $scope.query;
    $('#txt_name').val('"' + $rootScope.searchText + '"');
    $('#txt_name2').val('"' + $rootScope.searchText + '"');
}
```

If I have my rootscope value present I am updating my `ng-model="query.name"` But I can see value is not update because of ng-model..

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5eiOVjRJg95Q3Yt9yR6u?p=preview)

Why I am doing this.. 
On click on “Show details” button the selected information should be moved to an read only page(using default routing) and the details should be displayed to the user and click the browser back button should be navigated to the search page and still display the selected values.

To get this I am using rootScope to store the search value and I am populating this again.

I have shared the working code. Please suggest me if I can do this in better way.
I must be asking basic logic but I am new to angular.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to update the value and using ng-model your using 2 competing techniques?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? reading `query.name` from the user OR setting the value of `query.name` and respectively update the input control?

Comment: There must be more wrong with your code if $scope.query = $rootScope.searchText; $scope.query.name = $scope.query; does not work, can you post your complete html/js?

Comment: I am trying to add the plunker for this I am getting error.. I will share the demo..

Comment: @JavascriptCoder if you change the data in Jquery, which is not inside Angular's digest loop, the two way binding is gone. You need manually trigger a digest loop, but it's not a suggested way.

Comment: A tip to get faster into Angular. Throw out jQuery alltogether :)

Comment: so best way is use angular jqLite not jquery correct ?

Answer (score 2):

First off using jQuery and AngularJS in this manner is not the optimal solution.

Now, as to what is going on. You are essentially updating the view and angular has no idea the model value has changed. View and model value are two different entities. You need to call a $scope.digest() after the assignment or make the assignment in a 
    $scope.apply(function ()  {});
block.

This will make Angular aware of the change and cause the model to be updated. That said can you let us know why you are doing it this way exactly? We might be able to help you come up with a better, more efficient, pattern.

Comment: When I need to do a `$scope.apply()` I usually messed up somewhere, meaning I am not doing it the Angular way.

Comment: That's true @Mikey the cases where it would "truly be needed" are slim and far between. I use it mostly on error handling of I need to reject an erroneous input altogether and never allow it to render on the page. Really anything that works with $viewValue is a candidate for needing it, but those are truly special cases.

Comment: $scope.apply(function () {
      $('#txt_name').val('"' + $rootScope.searchText + '"');
      $('#txt_name2').val('"' + $rootScope.searchText + '"');
    });

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this.

Rootscope will work but I generally avoid putting things on it as much as possible. It can get heavy and slow your app. I would recommend creating a global value, 
   .value('myVal', {
        prop: '', 
        prop2: '' 
    });
injecting it and updating/reading where needed.

Also, the built in two way databinding using ngModel was put in place to eliminate the need for what you are doing. If that doesn't work then you can create a custom directive to either be passed or get the angular element and do your read/write there eliminating the need for jQuery.

Comment: can you please update my plunker to help me or please provide and code snippet...

Comment: I'll have to tomorrow. Plunker on phones is a tough thing to do.